# Execute dynamic query with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM H4 WHERE 1")
List getResult();
```

Instead of the query `"SELECT * FROM H4 WHERE 1"` I want to put a `String` variable containing query generated elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

`@Query`, like any other annotation, uses a compile time constant to define attributes. You can't define it's value in runtime unless you plan to hack the Spring Data JPA framework.

You should use either [Specifications with criteria](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications), [Query by example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) or JPQL to define and execute your dynamic query.

Comment: Criteria API is ugly. It's much cleaner to have a String that you create yourself. Is there a way to just run a String?

Answer (score 0):

Create constants and set the value as below.

```
@Query(value = ApplicationConstantClass.QUERY_STRING_CONSTANT)
List getResult();
```

or Use **`EntityManager`** or **`SessionFactory`** of hibernate to execute dynamically generated query.